# Seeking infinite product representations of $\pi$ (other than Wallis)

Tags: pi, infinite-product

I am looking for a list of as many representations of $\pi$ using "$\prod$" product notation; i.e., an infinite product for $\pi$. An example would be the Wallis product

$$\pi=4\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{\left(2n+1\right)^{2}}\right)$$

Do you know of any resources where I can find something like that?

Comment: It is well-known as **Wallis product**. Also it's proof is well-known.

Comment: @Nightflight, the OP clearly knows the name (they just didn't capitalize it). What they're asking for are other (presumably non-trivial) infinite products that produce $\pi$.

Comment: Googling on "product representations of pi" took me to https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/Pi/08/ShowAll.html among other sites.

Answer (score 1):

Some product formulas for $\pi$ from this site:

1.) [$(\frac{2 \times 2}{1 \times 3}) \times (\frac{4 \times 4}{3 \times 5}) \times (\frac{6 \times 6}{5 \times 7}) \times \cdots = \frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282486/frac2-times-21-times-3-times-frac4-times-43-times-5-times)

2.) [Why this is equal to $\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4276899/why-this-is-equal-to-pi)

3.) [An infinite product for $\frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017806/an-infinite-product-for-frac-pi2/4017868)

4.) [How to prove $ \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{(-1)^{n+1}n} \,= \frac{\pi}{2e}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971877/how-to-prove-prod-n-1-infty-left1-frac2n-right-1n1n?rq=1)

5.) [Prove that ${\pi\over2}=\left({2\over1}\right)^{1\over2}\left({2^2\over 1\cdot3}\right)^{1\over 4} \cdots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068183/prove-that-pi-over2-left2-over1-right1-over2-left22-over-1-cdot3?rq=1)